# Sprite Kit Making Node Fall

Tags: objective-c, xcode

right now I have a game that involves a character that will bounce forever, and my code will be below.  However, I want it to be so when I tap the screen (toucehsbegan), it will make the character fall to the from wherever it is, and resume to its normal jump height after the collision.  Thanks again (sorry, I'm new to coding)

For my character:

```
 person = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character"];
    person.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:person.size];
    person.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    person.position = CGPointMake(80, 365);
     person.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
 person.physicsBody.linearDamping=0.02f;
    [self addChild:person];
```

For my ground:

```
     ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ground.png"];
    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    ground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),200);
    [self addChild:ground];
```

Comment: This is a list of requirements, not a question. 
Please read ["How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head i would do something like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   character.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
}
```